# applying force to more than one object

Tags: c++

I have been working with chai-3d and opengl for creating a simulation for haptic device.

I have drawn a sphere which is positioned at center and another small spheres positioned around the center sphere, for each 15deg a sphere will be drawn based on the center sphere.below piece of code will draw center sphere.

```
cShapeSphere *sphere;
cShapeSphere* sphere2;

void sphere(void)
{
    float r1=0.020;
    float a=0.0;
    float b=0.0;
    float r2=r1/6;
    float th=15;
    double pi=3.14159265;
    sphere =new cShapeSphere(r1);
    world->addChild(sphere);
    sphere->setPos(0,a,b);

    //this will draw small sphere around the main sphere
    for(int j=1;j<=24;j++)
    {
        sphere2 =new cShapeSphere(r2);
        world->addChild(sphere2);
        sphere2->setPos(0,a+(r1+r2)*cos(th*j*pi/180),b+(r1+r2)*sin(th*j*pi/180));

        //this were i apply the force
        double strength = pow((sphere2->getRadius() - length) * 8000,2);
        force = (c_pos - spos) * strength;
        //the calculated force is sent to haptic device
        hapticDevice->setForce(force);
    }
}
```

When I tried to apply the force for all the smaller spheres, the force is detected only on the first smaller sphere positioned at 15 degree. Cannot apply force for the spheres positioned at 30 degrees to 360 degrees. The calculated force is sent to the haptice device. The problem is with the spheres, were 24 smaller spheres are drawn around the center sphere. The variable that I used to draw the 24 spheres is sphere2. Let us consider I'm drawing the spheres by giving different variable name say sphere 1 to 24, there I can apply the force without any problem because I use different variables but if I use same name for drawing all the spheres then the force is applied only at the first iteration. The force is not applied for other 23 iterations out of 24. I have to iterate the force along with the sphere position.

Comment: what is c_pos and spos, how do you use force variable?

Comment: c_pos is cursor position,s_pos is sphere position.the haptic cursor is a in sphere form ,collision detection is calculated based on the c_pos and s_pos.

Comment: if i understand right strength always the same, why not use constants for now as for debugging purposes?